# How to stub ES5 class constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

I can't find a proper way to stub es5 class object methods. It would also work if I could just return fake object/class when `new A()` is called.

What I have tried

```js
sinon.stub(A, 'hello').callsFake(() => console.log("stubbed"))
sinon.stub(A.prototype, 'hello').callsFake(() => console.log("stubbed"))
sinon.stub(A, 'constructor').callsFake(() => {hello: ()=>console.log("stubbed")})
```

```js
function A () {
  this.hello = function() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

new A().hello();
```

Expected output: stubbed

Current output: hello

Comment: This thread might help you https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1892

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf(A, sinon.stub().callsFake(function() { console.log('I am Super Stub!'); } ));`doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hello` is an [instance property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Instance_properties)...

...so a new function gets created and added as the `hello` property of each new instance.

So mocking it requires an instance:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

function A () {
  this.hello = function() {  // <= hello is an instance property
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

it('should stub hello', () => {
  const a = new A();  // <= create an instance
  sinon.stub(a, 'hello').callsFake(() => console.log("stubbed"));  // <= stub the instance property
  a.hello();  // <= logs 'stubbed'
});
```

---

If `hello` is changed to be a [prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods) it can be stubbed for all instances:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

function A () {
}
A.prototype.hello = function() {  // <= hello is a prototype method
  console.log("hello");
}

it('should stub hello', () => {
  sinon.stub(A.prototype, 'hello').callsFake(() => console.log("stubbed"));  // <= stub the prototype method
  new A().hello();  // <= logs 'stubbed'
});
```

Note that the prototype method approach is equivalent to this ES6 code:

```
class A {
  hello() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

...which seems like it might be how you intended to define `hello`.

Comment: It seems my approach was incorrect, I was trying to stub third party library "google-spreadsheet" which uses instance properties, I solved it by just overriding library with `proxyquire`. But you answered my question by saying that stubbing instance property before creating instance is not possible.